# Pyspark use DocumentAssembler on array<string>

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nlp, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am trying to use DocumentAssembler for array of strings. The documentation says: "The DocumentAssembler can read either a String column or an Array[String])".
But when I do a simple example:

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([[["Spark NLP is an open-source text processing library."]]]).toDF("text")
documentAssembler = DocumentAssembler().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("document")
result = documentAssembler.transform(data)

result.select("document").show(truncate=False)
```

I am getting an error

```
AnalysisException: [CANNOT_UP_CAST_DATATYPE] Cannot up cast input from "ARRAY<STRING>" to "STRING".
The type path of the target object is:
- root class: "java.lang.String"
You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field in the target object
```

Maybe I don't understand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just added an extra `[]` around the input

This is working:

```py
data = spark.createDataFrame([["Spark NLP is an open-source text processing library."]]).toDF("text")
documentAssembler = DocumentAssembler().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("document")
result = documentAssembler.transform(data)

result.select("document").show(truncate=False)
```

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|document                                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{document, 0, 51, Spark NLP is an open-source text processing library., {sentence -> 0}, []}]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: No, you are submitting a string as an input. I want to input an array of strings

Comment: So the API documentation accepts a string for each row of the Dataframe not an array https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/johnsnowlabs/nlp/DocumentAssembler.scala#L40

Comment: look at row 28-29 in your link: "The `DocumentAssembler` can read either a `String` column or an `Array[String]`. Additionally, [[setCleanupMode]] can be used to pre-process the text"

Comment: You are right, it looks like an issue in the API itself, i have tried both Scala and python version and I get the same error. I suggest to raise an issue at https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/issues

Comment: Yes, I wrote in the issue thread. Thanks anyway for your help